# Enable task to be deleted after X time

Tags: powershell, taskscheduler

How can I enable a task created using PowerShell's `Register-ScheduledTask` to be deleted If the task is not scheduled to run again?  As in `New-JobTrigger -Once -At $ScheduledTime`

The option is seen in the Task Scheduler GUI > Task Properties > Settings tab > The last checkbox option reads:

If the task is not scheduled to run again, delete it after: `<time period>`

[MS TechNet article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722178(v=ws.11).aspx)  Searching for enabling this option using PowerShell does not turn up any relevant results, mostly how to enable tasks and so on.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a [`New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj649824.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) like

```
New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet -DeleteExpiredTaskAfter <TimeSpan>

$STSet = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet -DeleteExpiredTaskAfter <TimeSpan>

Register-ScheduledTask mytask -Action <actionobject> -Settings $STSet
```

Comment: Good suggestion, but be aware that a task with only one trigger, configured to run once, will "expire" as soon as the trigger fires, so make sure the `TimeSpan` argument is *at least* as long as you would expect the task to maximally run

Comment: I'm not sure I have that cmdlet, I'm running v5 and `Get-Command *setting*` does not return the New-ScheduledTaskSEttingsSet cmdlet.

Comment: @user4317867, which OS version you are using? cause the documentation says *Windows Server 2012 R2 and Windows 8.1*

Comment: Ah yes, running Server 2008 R2.  I can bring my script over to Server 2012 and see what works.  -Thanks!

Comment: Just for fun `New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet -DeleteExpiredTaskAfter 1 | GM` returns `Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance#Root/Microsoft/Windows/TaskScheduler/MSFT_TaskSettings3` which has the property I'm looking for `DeleteExpiredTaskAfter` thus making the new question, can't I touch this using WMI?

Comment: @user4317867, May be but would suggest you to post another thread with this question and don't forget to accept this one though.

Comment: The `-settings` parameter is not available for the cmdlet `Register-ScheduledJob` which I found out is similar to Server 2012 and Win 8.1's `Register-ScheduledTask`